# Need help with php5.3 static inheritance

Tags: php, function, static, php-5.3

Having a little trouble with this static 'inheritance' in php 5.3
I need to test if a static function exists in static class but I need to test it from inside a parent static class.

I know in php 5.3 I can use the 'static' keyword to sort of simulate 'this' keyword.
I just can't find a way to test if function exists.

Here is an example:

```
// parent class
class A{

// class B will be extending it and may or may not have 
// static function name 'func'
// i need to test for it

    public static function parse(array $a){
        if(function_exists(array(static, 'func'){
            static::func($a);
        }
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public static function func( array $a ){
        // does something
    }
}
```

So now I need to execute `B::parse();`
the idea is that if subclass has a function, it will be used,
otherwise it will not be used.

I tried:

```
function_exists(static::func){}
isset(static::func){}
```

These 2 do not work.

Any ideas how to do this? 
By the way, I know about the possibility to passing a lambda function as a workaround, this is not an
option in my situation.

I have a feeling there is a very simple solution that I just can't think of right now.

Now I need to call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `function_exists` for classes and objects (methods), only functions. You have to use `method_exists` or `is_callable`. `isset` only works with variables. Also, `static` does not simulate `$this`, they are two completely different things.

That being said, in that specific case, you have to use `is_callable` with a quoted `static` keyword:

```
if (is_callable(array('static', 'func'))) {
    static::func();
}
```

or...

```
if (is_callable('static::func')) {
    static::func();
}
```

Comment: is_callable(array('static', 'func')) worked fine. I was concerned that if 'func' does not exist then is_callable may raise at least a warning that variable is not defined, but it does not. It returns false if func function does not exist, which is good.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public static function parse(array $a){
    if(function_exists(array(get_called_class(), 'func') {
/*...*/
```

See http://php.net/get_called_class